# wordpress not sending mails

Tags: wordpress, email, smtp

I am using gravity forms and contact form 7 and I dont know why but when I use my personal email with my domain, I dont get the mail. But when I change it to gmail account it magicly works.

Any ideas?

I have searched a bit and people said that they are having problems with gmail, so it have totaly confused me.

I have also tried to fix it using plugins but I am not sure about the configuration and the default didnt work.

I have also tried to getting around with code by commenting out, changing header..

```
require_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/registration-functions.php');" line...

require_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/pluggable-functions.php');
```

Comment: So you can't send emails using your own e-mail as a FROM e-mail or what?

Comment: I dont receive the emails at all. Not in Inbox, Spam or anywhere else-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found that there is a conflict betweens our server and google apps, after totally turning off our mail server the issues were solved

Answer (score 0):

Try sending mail though SMTP, I use this with Google Apps and it works nicely: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/configure-smtp/

Comment: Providing you have configured it correct, then your mail server is not configured properly. Try using your domain with Google Apps (Free), with your custom domain.

Comment: I think that Google Apps cause this problem because it have occurred after going to google apps

Comment: Hmmm, are you sure you are using the correct port? It is a common mistake as Google Apps do not use the default. "
smtp.gmail.com (use authentication). 
Use SSL encryption. 
Port for SSL: 465." 
Also ensure these ports are not blocked by your firewall/IP Rules. Finally check you have configured Google Apps properly, with correct MX records.

Answer (score 0):

You already see your spam box !

Answer (score 0):

There is a great plugin called wp-mail-smtp that works really well in some of these situations. You can specify the outgoing email server, plus a username and password.

I've had to use in the pass mostly on Windows Server hosted websites.

Here's a link.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/

Answer (score 0):

I believe problem is from the Host Server not allowing you to send email from external forms. You can confirm by filling the form and send it to same email as with your host domain.